# How to insert data to IIS server through browser using link from android

Tags: php, android, iis

How to insert data to the ISS server using browser. I have this link but it can not work, it only dowload the file but can not insert data http://117.121.237.226:7777/addemployee.php.

My Employer server link is http://117.121.237.226:7777/ and i want to insert data to his data base using this link. So how caN i DO THAT

Comment: I don't think IIS server can run `PHP`.

Comment: @KNeerajLal http://117.121.237.226:8082/m/addemployee.php please chekc out this url now it can run php file

Comment: @KNeerajLal but i don't know how to access the data base using this php file

Comment: But it is not running the scricpt. It is only downloading the PHP script.

Comment: @KNeerajLal so, can you tell me the way, how can i access the data base, because the php file is placed in www folder, and i want toa ccess data base using the file in this folder becaue i only can access these files

Comment: Which is the db? MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: @KNeerajLal This is SQL server

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc793139(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: IIS server can't run PHP files. You need some other server (Apache for example).